# Problems saving the state, extremely stumped

Tags: android, save, restore

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. So here is the code, my `onSaveInstanceState` is simply not saving so to make it simple I focused on one thing to try and make it work, and still nothing.

```
    @Override
     public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putString("test_time", vitTimeSet1.getText().toString());
```

}

And just so you guys know every detail, I have a back button too in which I use to test if the instance restores. Here it is.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tools.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    finish();

    return true;
```

As you can see, this toolbar back button calls `finish();` so that when you come back there are not multiple instances of this activity running. And now here is the code in `onCreate` that calls for the `TextView` to set the text of the saved string.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(outState);
      if (outState != null){
          vitTimeSet1.setText(outState.getString("test_time"));

          }else{
```

Upon pressing the back button and then reopening the activity, the TextView stays as if it was never saved upon storing `vitTimeSet1`. SO what problems do you see that would keep this from being saved and then restored?

Edit:
The back button takes you back to a menu (the back button I created for the toolbar). So when you press it to return to the above activity, it opens a new instance without being restored. I call `finish();` upon hitting that back button, so if I remove it, all it does when clicking this button to open the activity above

```
        vitals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vitals);
    vitals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            Class goVitals = Class.forName("com.vexos.emspal.Vitals");
            Intent goIntent = new Intent(Tools.this, goVitals);
            startActivity(goIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
```

It opens a NEW instance with still no saved values. It does not resume the old instance with the saved values. However, if you hit the back button to KILL this new instance, it reveals the saved instance with the stored value. `finish();` seems to be the only way to get it to not do this, but it kills the activity so things may not be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using finish().
As per http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed.

Edit:
Activity instance is most commonly saved when navigating away to a new activity and then coming back and restoring the saved state. Starting the same activity again should not restore the previous state, but start fresh instead.

Edit:
In the case where multiple instances of the same Activity must be supported per task, one could send the state bundle in the intent passed to startActivity.

Comment: When I don't include finish();, it opens multiple instances of the activity when I use the back button I created above. When it use it, and it takes you to the menu, and then reopen it, you'll reopen a NEW instance of the activity and not actually restore the old one although the old one still exists. To see the only one, hitting the phones back button will close out the new instance, and reveal the old instance.

Comment: In that case the behavior of the "synthetic" back button is not the one desired, supposing you want to reproduce the hardware back button behavior. The hardware back button does not start a new activity, but instead navigates backward in the [activity stack of the task](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). If its just for test purposes you could accept having multiple instances or test with different activities?

Comment: The idea is to fill things out in this activity, and if you somehow need to go back and use another tool and then return, you can return to the activity where you left off rather than having to redo everything. The app kind of depends on being able to go back and forth through tools throughout the use of the app in order to be practical for it's use in EMS. I managed to save this stuff to globals, but that purpose of that was to save it to a form that can be printed out for legal purposes and to compress all of your information into an easy to read document.

Comment: I edited to show the activity the back button I created sends you to, or at least the button that reopens the activity that I posted above that won't save anything. I even included finish(); in this button to prevent opening multiple instances of it when you press it and come back. Without finish(); in either of these buttons, it will continuously create a new instance of each, so that pressed the phones back button will require several clicks in order to close them all out. It's not restoring the instance, it's just making new ones.

Comment: Adding "singleTask" in the Manifest for the activity fixes my issue. Problem solved.

Comment: If only one instance of the Activity is allowed in a task, that fits great. If the same Activity should be present multiple times in different states it will not be possible.